# How to filter out a column value when another column contains a value in SQl

Tags: sql, toad

How can I filter out a value in one column if a value in another column is present?  I'm trying to remove all C's in the CODE column if it is accompanied by a '-' in the Description column.

```
CODE |  Description
A      -
A      -
B      -
B      -
C      stuff
C      -
```

In the 'CODE' column, I want to remove the values 'C' if the Description = '-'.

The end result would look like the table below with the C & - removed.

```
CODE |  Description
A      -
A      -
B      -
B      -
C      stuff
```

Of note, the Description column is a custom field using CASE WHEN.

In excel, I would just create a dummy conditional column and then filter 'C' &'-' out.  I'm not sure how to go about doing this in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to express this uses `not`:

```
where not (code = 'C' and Description = '-')
```

This seems quite close to the logic as your express it.

This is equivalent to:

```
where code <> 'C' or Description <> '-')
```

Note that both these solutions assume that `code` and `description` are not `NULL`.  They can be modified to handle that as well, but that does not seem necessary based on the data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT CODE, Description 
FROM your_table_name 
WHERE (CODE Not Like 'C' And Description Not Like '-');
```

Also, I would advise keeping the field/column names of the same case such as 'Code' and 'Description' or 'CODE' and DESCRIPTION'. It is a much better practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
    select 
    t1.Code,
    t1.Description
    from MyTable t1
    where t1.code not in (select code from MyTable where Description not like '-') 
    union All
    select * from MyTable
    where Description not like '-'
    order by code asc
```

primary:

[image: primary]

result:

[image: Result]